# jquery onmouseover and onmouseout not working with IE

Tags: jquery

the following code works fine with Opera but not with IE 8

I have dtest2 div element on page, for testing purpose I am trying to change the content of div element on mouseover and mouseout events of an image.

html:

```
  <a ><img  title='' class='imgclass' src='images/image1.jpg'  onmouseover="f1('1')"  onmouseout="f2('1');"    ></a>
```

Jquery :

```
function f1(id)
{   

 $('#dtest2').html("Test "+id);
}
    function f2(id)
{   
        $('#dtest2').html("Test 2 "+id);
}
```

with Opera it works normal. With IE it works 1 time or few times, then stops working. any specific command for IE ?

These images are coming from database, id is there unique number from database .

Thanks

Comment: Works all the time in IE8, IE9, latest version of FF and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/bYfQ2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing your idioms here a little bit. It should still work, but you'll probably have better results (and definitely neater code) by doing things the "jQuery way," which involves separating code from the HTML.

So, first the HTML:

```
<a>
    <img title='' class='imgclass' src='images/image1.jpg'>
</a>
```

It's the same as what you had, without the `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` attributes.

Now, the jQuery, preferably in a separate file that you use `<script src="url.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` to load in.

```
$('img.imgclass').hover(function() {
    $('#dtest2').html('Test');
}, function() {
    $('#dtest2').html('Test2');
});
```

One of the major advantages of jQuery is that it is designed to smooth all browser incompatibilities so that you just need one code for all browsers.

As for the `id` that you want to pass to your function, that's a little trickier. Where is that number coming from and what does it mean? That will affect how to handle that.

If nothing else, you can include it in your HTML with an HTML5 `data-` attribute, like so:

```
<a>
    <img title='' class='imgclass' src='images/image1.jpg' data-hover-id="1">
</a>
```

You can then retrieve it with the following change to the jQuery:

```
$('img.imgclass').hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('hover-id');
    $('#dtest2').html('Test ' + id);
}, function() {
    var id = $(this).data('hover-id');
    $('#dtest2').html('Test2 ' + id);
});
```

EDIT for edited question: Since they're unique IDs coming from the database, it probably makes sense to just use them as the `id` of the `img`. However, you should not use purely-numerical `id`s. So whatever you're using to pull the ID from the database should prepend something, perhaps just `i` or `img`.

Then your HTML will look like

```
<img id="i1" title="" src="images/image1.jpg">
```

And your jQuery can access that with `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `$(this).data('hover-id')`.

Comment: but how to pass id variable   ?

Comment: @SamirMemmedov: See my edited version for some discussion on that. You should edit your question with more information on what that ID is, though.

Comment: data-hover-id="1" how to use that id with jquery ? like to have text like "Test "+id ?

Comment: @SamirMemmedov: Actually, I forgot the jQuery half. See the revised version.

Comment: @DragoonWraith: If IE8 is tested on I'm not sure HTML5 attributes are valid html but they still could be used though I guess.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: The nice thing about the `data-` attributes is that browsers have basically always ignored attributes they don't know, and JavaScript has always just returned them as-is. AFAIK you can just make up an attribute if you want. This will just validate under HTML5 and will never get screwed up by a later HTML update using that attribute name.

Comment: @DragoonWraith: They still work alright but fail html validation. Test it here: http://validator.w3.org/check. Produces `there is no attribute "DATA-HOVER-ID"` when validating against html 4. So if you are required to write valid html for Html 4 you may need to use an alternative. But yes, it still functionaly works.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: If you have the correct doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), it validates just fine (with a warning about the HTML5 validator being experimental).

Comment: @DragoonWraith: It passes when using Html5 doctype, just mentioning it as you may be required to program against a html4  doctype. Your answer is perfect either way, just thought I mention it, that's all :)

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer.  $('img.imgclass').hover is not worked I had to use div and image inside div to use this method. I dont know why $('img.imgclass').hover is not working, but $('div.divclass').hover is working fine